# Incrementing Height Variable in Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, nodes, increment

I am trying to use an iterative method to calculate the height of my binary search tree, but I am having trouble figuring out when to add 1 to my height variable, aka when there is a new level of nodes. Here is my insertion method:

```
public Node insertRec(Node x, String key) {
        if (x == null)
        {
            x = new Node(key);              // if bst is empty, add new node and return
            height++;
            return x;
        }

        if (key.compareTo(x.key) < 0) {         
            x.left = insertRec(x.left, key);    // recursive calls to find correct spot to insert in the tree
        }
        else if (key.compareTo(x.key) > 0) {
            x.right = insertRec(x.right, key);
        }   
        return x;                                       // returns unchanged node
    }
```

As you can see, right now I am just adding 1 to the height when a new node is added and then I use another method to just return that variable, but that is not a correct number for the height. I believe I need some sort of test so that if there is a new level of nodes, then 1 is added to the height, but I'm not sure where to start with that.

Comment: Don't _increment_ height, _compute_ height in terms of the height of the child nodes.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution for your case is to add an `height` variable to your function, then you can compute the maxHeight after the Node creation:

```
public Node insertRec(Node x, String key, int newHeight) {
        if (x == null)
        {
            x = new Node(key);              
            if (newHeight > maxHeight) 
                maxHeight = newHeight;

            return x;
        }

        if (key.compareTo(x.key) < 0) {         
            x.left = insertRec(x.left, key, ++newHeight);    // recursive calls to find correct spot to insert in the tree
        }
        else if (key.compareTo(x.key) > 0) {
            x.right = insertRec(x.right, key, ++newHeight);
        }   
        return x;                                       // returns unchanged node
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a recursive call it is quite easy:

```
public int getHeight(Node x)
{
    int height = 0;
    if(x.left != null)
        height = Math.max(height, getHeight(x.left);
    if(x.right != null)
        height = Math.max(height, getHeight(x.right);
    
    return height + 1;
}
```

But since you want an iterative method, you need to implement a stack yourself and keep a map of the current values:

```
public int getHeight(Node root)
{
    HashMap<Node, Integer> heights = new HashMap<>();
    Stack<Node> toVisit = new Stack<>();
    toVisit.push(root);
    
    while(!toVisit.isEmpty())
    {
        Node x = toVisit.peek(); // Before removing the node from the stack, check that his children have been already visited
        
        if(x.left != null && !heights.containsKey(x.left))
        {
            //Left node has not been visited yet
            toVisit.push(x.left);
            continue;
        }
        if(x.right != null && !heights.containsKey(x.right))
        {
            //Right node has not been visited yet
            toVisit.push(x.right);
            continue;
        }
        int height = 0;
        if(x.left != null)
            height = Math.max(height, heights.get(x.left));
        if(x.right != null)
            height = Math.max(height, heights.get(x.right));
        
        heights.put(x, height + 1);
        toVisit.pop(); //Remove node x from the stack, it has been successfully visited
     }

     return heights.get(root);
}
```

Nota: I didn't test the code